# How to create a Pivot based on Date Range and Condition

Tags: mysql, pivot

I created a view in mysql that looks like this (v_exp)

[image]

and I have another table that looks like this.

[image]

How can I make a[image] pivot look like this?

My target here is to generate that report based on the following criteria

`Member and Date Range`

TYSM for help

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: MySQL doesn't contain any native support for pivoting. It's generally a pain in the neck to use native SQL to generate this kind of result. You may want to use a host language (like php or java) for this.

Comment: @O.Jones takes for the info.. let me check if i can do that